# Casting a RGB string to a Color type

Tags: c#, colors, system.drawing

I am reading from a file that has a list of RGB values, i.e.

```
0,1,6
0,2,6
0,43,170
0,42,168
0,44,175
0,44,176
0,44,176
0,221,255
0,222,255
0,222,255
```

I have stored all these values into a `string[]` array, with this constructor:

```
    public Program(int rows, String fileLocation) {

        int i;
        String line;
        count = 0;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
        stringArray = new String[rows];

        try {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileLocation);
            for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    stringArray[i] = line;
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

I wanted to convert these current `String`s to `Color` values, as they are just RGB values in the form of Strings.

So I used this method:

```
    public Color[] convertToColorArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            colorArray[i] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(stringArray[i]);
        }
        return colorArray;
    }
```

With that said, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Telling me I have an invalid arg. I understand that the argument is not necessarily something like this `255,255,255` which are three `ints` separated by commas, but my `string` input is in that format. What is it I should do? Should I cast it to something? Should I simply store those values into a `Color[]` in my constructor in the beginning?

Comment: you need to parse your string to int, and split it before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at the overloads for [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), they all expect `int` to be passed in. So no, you can't just pass in a string and expect it to work. However it is not hard to turn your string in to a set of ints.

```
public Color[] convertToColorArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        //This gives us an array of 3 strings each representing a number in text form.
        var splitString = stringArray[i].Split(','); 

        //converts the array of 3 strings in to an array of 3 ints.
        var splitInts = splitString.Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToArray(); 

        //takes each element of the array of 3 and passes it in to the correct slot
        colorArray[i] = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(splitInts[0], splitInts[1], splitInts[2]); 
    }
    return colorArray;
}
```

This code all assumes your source file is well formed so that `string.Split` will always return at least 3 arrays and `int.Parse` will never fail at parsing the input.

Comment: The entire file is nicely structured, so it should work based on the 0 to 2 indexes.

Answer (score 3):

I use an extension method of string to handle without throws using transparent as fallback:

```
    private static System.Drawing.Color ToColor(this string color)
    {
        var arrColorFragments = color?.Split(',').Select(sFragment => { int.TryParse(sFragment, out int fragment); return fragment; }).ToArray();

        switch (arrColorFragments?.Length)
        {
            case 3:
                return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(arrColorFragments[0], arrColorFragments[1], arrColorFragments[2]);
            case 4:
                return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(arrColorFragments[0], arrColorFragments[1], arrColorFragments[2], arrColorFragments[3]);
            default:
                return System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

Note that I'm using C# 7. Maybe you'll have to tweak for C# version that you are using.

Comment: I find `FromArgb1` has overloads, so you don't need separate calls for RGB and ARGB. Your code can be reduced to a simple `if/else` with 2 choices: a colour and transparent.

Comment: Which overload you suppose that I should use? I can't find the method `FromArgb1` that you mentioned (with 1 as suffix).

Comment: The `1` was a typo. Which overload you use depends on whether you have an alpha value or not.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're trying to call takes 1-4 parameters

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Assuming you're sure you have three values in each line - this should work

```
string[] splitArray = stringArray[i].Split(',');

System.Drawing.FromARGB(Int32.Parse(splitArray[0]),Int32.Parse(splitArray[1]),Int32.Parse(splitArray[2]);
```

You can write this cleaner if you convert the Array into an array of int[] beforehand

```
int[] intArray = splitArray.Select(sa => Int32.Parse(sa)).ToArray();
```

then you can just call intArray[0] et cetera.

Comment: The three parameters I am using are simply `R`, `G`, and `B`. The fourth one also includes `A` which is `alpha`, but I have no need for `alpha` :-).

Comment: (Sorry, removed reference to the 4th one. You don't actually 'need it', you can just call the overloaded one)

Answer (score 1):

The FromArgb method expects a single ARGB Int32 value, not what you want. Try this instead:

```
var items = stringArray[i].Split(",").Select(k => int.Parse(k)).ToArray();
colorArray[i] = Color.FromArgb(items[0], items[1], items[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var colors = File.ReadLines(fname)
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(p => Color.FromArgb(byte.Parse(p[0]), byte.Parse(p[1]), byte.Parse(p[2])))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to take the string, split it by the comma delimiter and then finally for each one, convert it into an int and then finally, put it in the FromArgb method.

Answer (score 0):

FromArgb has an overloaded method that accepts 3 integers as parameters, one for R one for G and one for B.

Split your stringArray[i] into 3 integer parts(should be easy, bcoz they r separated by commas) and pass them to the method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use method `ColorTranslator.FromHtml`.

Sample code:

```
string hexCode = "#FF0000";
Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexCode);
Console.WriteLine(color);
```

Output :

```
Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0]
```

Source : https://www.techieclues.com/blogs/converting-string-to-color-in-csharp